# Plotting a simple time series in ggplot.

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a simple time series using `ggplot()` or `qplot()`. The horizontal axis will be the date and the vertical axis a number, a simple line chart will suffice.
Normally, one would need to melt the rectangle data before using `ggplot()`. However, I am stuck with this:

```
net.t <- structure(c(6, 11, 0, -1, -13), .Names = c("2011-09-01", "2011-12-01", 
"2012-03-01", "2012-06-01", "2012-09-01"))

net.t.m <- melt(net.t,id="var")

#After melting 'net.t', it became a vector or array? how to plot that?

qplot(net.t.m,main="Net Promotion Score")+geom_smooth(se=F, size=1.5)
nps.t+labs(y="NPS",x="Year Quarter")+geom_text(aes(label =value),size = 3, vjust = -1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `net.t` is just a vector and once you melt it, you have a data frame with only one column. The dates are the names of the rows, not the entries. One solution is to add a column of dates:

```
net.t.m$date <- as.Date(rownames(net.t.m))
ggplot(net.t.m, aes(x=date, y=value)) + geom_point() +
   geom_smooth(method="loess", se=F, size=1.5) +
   labs(y="NPS",x="Year Quarter") +
   geom_text(aes(label =value),size = 3, vjust = -1)
```